# Question about panning

Tags: mixing

I did read this on the internet,but just couldn't find the answer.
Goal is to make room for voice in the mix.
If i have background music (Stereo) And then separate channels in mono.Pan lef/right.Would that make room for voice or just make music wider?
I apologize if this question is kinda stupid.

Comment: There's an entire answer already devoted to how to make room for vocals: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/30826/how-can-i-get-the-vocals-to-stand-out-better-in-the-mix-when-recording/30836#30836

Answer (score 3):

"Making room" also means "carving out a space in the frequency range" using EQ: you find the sweet-spot for the vocalist's voice and for the song, then you duck the bass track, guitar(s) etc etc in that range.