# trying to get a better bass sound

Tags: mixing

first sorry for my Eng.i have a problem with my mixing. my music style is edm and when i mix my music, everything is ok except that when i looking to my 32 band monitor plugin, i see that around 100-200 hrtz, is kinda low( compare to other freq of my music). i know that this area is fundamental for bass, but when i use synth bass, if i write the bass in lower octaves, it wont havr the sound i want and when i write it in higher octaves, it will lack the bass in 100-200 hertz. i also tried to use eq in that area, but i doesnt do much. i am really confuse, could you plz help me?[image]

Comment: First, forget about what the monitor plugin shows on a screen. We don't listen to music with our eyes. How does it ***sound***? If it sounds ok, ignore the plugin. If it doesn't sound ok, let us know what sounds wrong.

Comment: The aspect that seems to be missed is that of the reproduction facilities. Will it be listened to on headphones, studio monitors, through a huge p.a., on someone's phone?  Each will give a rather different sound, so that in itself will be affected by the eq. on the track. And, anyway - what constitutes a 'good bass sound'? Quite subjective, judging by comments from fellow band players...

Comment: In the meantime, check out some of these mixing tips, but any time you see "vocals", think of the "bass" instead. https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/30826/how-can-i-get-the-vocals-to-stand-out-better-in-the-mix-when-recording/30836#30836

Comment: The officially supported way to embed audio snippets here is [through SoundCloud](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled).

Comment: @Tim One of the major tasks of mixing (and moreso of mastering) is to make a mix that works at least well enough on as many different listening systems as possible. In any case, with the metering posted (still would be nice to have audio) we can clearly see way too much at 1 kHz and 10 kHz and hardly anything between 50 and 500 Hz. We can't mix with our eyes but that meter is definitely telling us something is wrong that has nothing to do with the listening environment.

Answer (score 3):

Without audio it's hard to be sure. Here are some common ways that the bass can be weak in a recording.

- Too much compression. Compression can "squeeze" out the low frequencies and the time constants that sound good for higher frequencies can ruin low frequencies. Try reducing or eliminating any stereo bus compression. Alternatively, use parallel compression or a side chain to prevent the loss of low-end.
- Too much of other frequency ranges. If you are compressing and/or limiting the stereo bus, then the most prevalent frequency will dominate the others. The more compression and limiting you add, the more you affect the frequency balance. Try reducing mids and highs a bit to help the lows come through better.
- Improper source material. It's really hard or impossible to add frequencies that aren't already there, so if your bass sounds are not good to start with, you won't be able to do much to pump them up in the mix. Go back to the instruments that contribute to the low end and make sure they are making the kinds of sounds you need to fit into the mix.
- Polarity and phase issues. If you have multiple sources of low end that are partly but not completely the same (e.g., two different DIs from a bass guitar or two mics on the kick drum), then they could be canceling each other out. Try reducing the number of sources that are providing low frequency content. Put high pass filters on any sources that are not meant to fill in the low end (guitars, vocals, violin, snare drum, etc.).

One way to figure out what's going on is to take the mix apart and look at the pieces. Find the primary bass instrument like a bass guitar or synth and solo it. Bypass all effects. Make sure the instrument is putting out the kind of low end you need all by itself. If not, try a *little* EQ (try cutting mids instead of boosting lows) and/or compression to see if you can enhance it a bit. If you still aren't getting the right low end, you may have to re-record or use a different sound depending on what kind of source it is.

If you *are* getting the low end you want from that one instrument, then something is happening when you put the whole mix together. Make sure you make room for the low end instruments by making the other instruments thinner sounding. Use high pass and low shelf filters to clear a lane for the bass sounds. Add bass sounds one at a time and listen carefully. If you add a sound and it makes the overall bass sound weaker, then you have some kind of problem - possibly with polarity or phase. Generally less is more when it comes to the low end. Having two to four tracks for the whole low end of a mix is going to sound "bigger" than trying to stack up 12 tracks of bass synths or whatever. Too many tracks will just get in the way of each other.

Oh yeah, this:

> when i use synth bass, if i write the bass in lower octaves, it wont havr the sound i want and when i write it in higher octaves, it will lack the bass in 100-200 hertz.

When I make a synth bass patch, I almost always have at least two oscillators that are an octave apart. That way it's got the higher octave sound for the *sound* and the lower octave sound for the *bass* going. Another way to do this with one oscillator is to get the right filter and filter envelope settings. Add a bit of resonance to the filter and have the envelope sweep it down fairly fast. You want the filter up high at first to get the tone and articulation and then have it sweep low to emphasize the low end (with the resonance). If you can keyboard track your filter, then turn that on. Play with the settings until it starts to sound classic, almost cheesy in a way, but it will be good.

Another way to do it is to use hard sync, but that's going back to two oscillators. Turn on sync and change oscillator frequencies to figure out which one changes the note. Set the one that changes the note back to the default note and set the other oscillator frequency either above or below the other oscillator (probably below) to get a low end growl. If you can assign an envelope to oscillator frequency, then again sweeping the oscillator from high to low can help you get a balance of tone and low end.

Remember that you need some mids in the bass or the lows will be hard to hear. You'll be able to feel them a bit (with the right speakers) but they won't have good note articulation. Don't use EQ to cut out all the mids and highs in your bass synth. In fact, you might want to boost around 500 Hz and/or 900 Hz on the bass to make it come out, and cut the same range in the other instruments to get them out of the way. If things sound crowded and muddy in the bass, try a gentle, narrow cut around 250 Hz just until it cleans up. Too much cut there will ruin everything. Try to avoid boosting the lows too much - they should already be there or something is wrong. You can boost 80 - 150 Hz or so to goose it up a bit but if you're temped to add more than 3 dB then you may have to go back to your bass synth tone and fix it there. Boosting at or below 50 Hz is probably just going to rob you of power bandwidth and it *might* make things more interesting for people with expensive subwoofers but more likely it will just ruin the whole mix.

Remember, the bass sounds should usually be *balanced* and have a wide frequency spectrum. **Don't** cut out all the highs from the bass, just leave them there to do their thing. **Do** reduce the low end on instruments that aren't bass instruments or low drums. Because of how our ears work the low end can be a lot trickier to mix.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you included audio in the question, along with a description of the tone you wanna reach, but some quicker tips would be:

- Cut frequencies above 9k
- Way less on the 2k to 9k range
- More on the lower frequencies
- A bit more on the middle frequencies if you want more definition

Answer (score 0):

If you still want the bass sound but want the sub bass range of audio to be heard, I suggest adding a sub bass (a basic sine or triangle wave patch on a synth will do), highpass your synth bass you have from about 100 Hz onwards and you'll have that sound that EDM production usually has. Make sure that you have the same kind of bass pattern and notes from your synth bass playing on your sub bass.

Alternatively, if the synth you're using has an oscillator that is unused, maybe utilise that and add a sine or triangle wave sound through that.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your worries sound like you want to have your final mix be as close to pink noise in the spectrum as possible.  Why?

Looking at the spectrum is a good idea for figuring out how to approach problems with the mix.  But the first step is actually having a problem.

You don't judge or fix a photograph using a histogram before even looking at the photograph.

Bass is the harmonic foundation of music, and much of the melodic framework is constructed octaves above it.  Filling everything in between strongly with material would muddy up the results: you don't put more violas in an orchestra than violins, and you don't split the cellos into more (and stronger) voices than the violins, and don't forget that the cellos' overtones actually play in the viola and violin range as well.

So you really need to *listen* to your music rather than look at its spectrograms.  If it sounds balanced and reasonably transparent (the various instruments' purposes are apparent without getting plastered over), you are fine.  If not, the spectrogram can help with figuring out problem areas.

Equalizing can help with making instruments more compatible.  The way to equalize is almost always to tone *down* ranges that are less important for the character of some instrument: equalizing is good for *creating* some space in your spectrogram, not for *filling* space.  So the separate spectrograms of conflicting instruments are quite more interesting than that of the result for figuring out where equalization can help improving your mix.